# how to htaccess 301 redirect pages with a question mark

Tags: html, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to 301 redirect several files that don't exist on my website anymore. My website used to be on Adobe Business Catalyst, but I put it on a normal server without a CMS, so now I am left with a lot of asp extensions that got indexed by Google.

I want to redirect <kbd>http://www.example.com/FAQRetrieve.aspx?ID=51029</kbd> to <kbd>http://www.example.com</kbd>.

I tried using this code

```
Redirect 301 /FAQRetrieve.aspx?ID=51681 http://www.example.com/
```

But it doesn't work. Instead, when I go to that page I see my 404 error page.

I think I need to use Query Strings somehow, but I've never used them before and can't find any relevant examples. Can anyone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot match query string using `Redirect` directive. Use mod_rewrite rules instead. Keep this in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ID=51681$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^FAQRetrieve\.aspx$ http://www.example.com/? [L,NC,R=301]
```